# Path to delete resource link in Coffeescript

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, coffeescript

I can create a delete resource link in the view like this:

```
<%= link_to 'Destroy', quote, method: :delete, 
                                data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
```

And I can make AJAX-request in the coffee script file:

```
$.ajax(url: "/test").done (html) ->
    $("#results").append html
```

I want to avoid the hardcoded links in the CoffeeScript file.  How can I set the URL for resource deletion in the CoffeeScript file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might want to take a look @ [js-routes](https://github.com/railsware/js-routes)